# Handling Internet Connection throughout app

Tags: ios, swift

My app has around 30 screens. Suppose a user is on a screen and internet disconnects, I want to show a no internet connection view.

One way is to add a UIView in every VC and show it with a retry button, which the user can tap again. But this step would need adding the UIView on all screens, which I don't want to do.

Is there a generic way to achieve this? Like creating a UIViewController and presenting it when internet available. But even then on the dismissal of the view controller, how would I know which screen the user was on and what APIs to call again.

> NOTE: I am trying for a solution where I do not need to add code in
>   every VC and handle it from one class.

Is it confusing? Let me know in the comments and I will try to rephrase it and make it more clear.

Comment: Yeah, I have do that in my application. I have shown a no Internet Connection View on all the screens of Application, But I have to just show the Dismiss button and then that view is dismiss. But your requirement is different you have to call the Api Again, When you would detect the internet connection.

Comment: You have to create a Singleton Class. Inside of Singleton class you have to detect the internet connection is working fine or not. Does you know about singleton?

Comment: @MandeepSingh yes i know. Bit singleton wont solve the issue. options i have is notifications and protocols. But still i will have to make all view controllers conform to it. I am here for better suggestions but i guess i will have to stick to the basics only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before diving into the solution below, I would like to point out error handling by making use of the **responder chain**. John Sundell wrote an excellent article on how to implement error handling using the responder chain. [Propagating user-facing errors in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/propagating-user-facing-errors-in-swift/)

A possible solution is having a protocol for example `NoConnectionPresentable` implemented by the view-controllers and have a property on the networking-client accepting an object conforming to `NoConnectionPresentable`.

`NoConnectionPresentable` -protocol has as function `showNoConnectionAlert` to show an alert. It also has a default implementation of `showNoConnectionAlert` function, so there is no need to implement this on every view-controller. Second it has a property `retry` which is a closure to be execute when a retry is needed. This `retry` closure is specific to the view-controller and needs to be implemented in every view-controller.

Example of `NoConnectionPresentable`:

```
protocol NoConnectionPresentable: class {
    var retryCallback: (() -> Void)? { get }
    func showNoConnectionAlert()
}

extension NoConnectionPresentable where Self: UIViewController {
    func showNoConnectionAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "no connection",
                          message: "it appears you dont have a connection",
                          preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(title: "okay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(title: "retry", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { _ in
                self.retryCallback?()
            })
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Whenever the network-client needs to perform some networking action it first checks for the connection. If there is no connection call the no-connection-presentable object to show an alert for example.

Example of network-client:

```
class NetworkService {
    weak var noConnectionPresenter: NoConnectionPresentable?

    func get() {
        // check connections, no connection?
        noConnectionPresenter?.showNoConnectionAlert()
    }
}
```

Example view-controller:

```
class NewsViewController: UIViewController, NoConnectionPresentable {
    lazy var retryCallback: (() -> Void)? = {
        self.load()
    }

    unowned let networkService: NetworkService
    init(networkService: NetworkService) {
        self.networkService = networkService
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        networkService.noConnectionPresenter = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.load()
        }
    }

    private func load() {
        print("loading")
        networkService.get()
    }
}
```

This implementation assumes every view-controller is instantiated with its own networking-client. If the networking-client is defined once, and used in all view-controllers, make sure to reassign the current view-controller to `noConnectionPresenter` -property of the networking-client on appearance(`viewWillAppear`) for example. So the visible view-controller will show the alert.